# If else not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple program where I'm asking to user to put `name` and `age` and after that using if else to print the result.

I want when is put age 20 so result should come

> Congratulation Edit your age is 20  and you can find the truth

but It is not working here is the code which I'm using.

**Code**

```
name = input("what is your name \n")
print('Nice to meet you', name, "!!")
age = input("Your Age ? \n")

if age > 18:
    print('Congratulation ' + name + ' your age is '+ str(age), ' and you can find the truth ')
else:
    print('Sorry ' + name + 'your age is '+ str(age), ' and you can also find the truth if you start from today')
```

and error which I'm getting after running my code.

**Error**

```
what is your name 
Edit
Nice to meet you Edit !!
Your Age ? 
20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/Project/input_user.py", line 5, in <module>
    if age > 18:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Help me out here to resolve this problem.

Comment: `if int(age)`  is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the error message:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

You are trying to compare a string and an integer. You have to convert the input to `int` first:

```
age = int(input("Your Age ? \n"))
```

This will allow you to compare it with numbers.

Alternatively, convert it when you need to compare with numbers

```
if int(age) > 18:
```

But this is really more of a usability issue now. It would be better to simply convert it to `int` as soon as you get it, as age you probably need the numerical value more than the string value.

Comment: No need for write an answer when you can comment this

Comment: Well it answers the question... Therefore it is technically an answer. You could have posted an answer too.

Comment: I thought no need for this short answer

Comment: Not all answers have to be long :) As long as it's correct, answers the question, and is helpful (or, as the up-vote prompt says, "useful"). When the problem is caused by something as simple as type conversion, there isn't _that_ much to say.

Comment: It is working thanks @Arc676

Comment: You Right , I thought Shortly comment is more useful and more brighter for asker person